# How can I configure static IP on ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: netplan

Have 2 Ubuntu Servers. Tried to configure static IP on both of them. Server 1 everything is working file. Server 2 giving error:

> /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml:10:18: Invalid YAML: inconsistent
>   indentation:
>              dhcp4: false
>                   ^

file /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml:

```
network:  
    ethernets:  
        eno1:  
            addresses:[10.0.0.2/24]  
            dhcp4: false  
            gateway4: 10.0.0.1  
            nameservers:  
                addresses: [8.8.8.8,1.1.1.1]  
    version: 2
```

Answer (score 3):

I followed instructions [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) to update netplan config file and it worked. The following uses the correct indentation:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eno1:
     dhcp4: no
     addresses: [10.0.0.2/24]
     gateway4: 10.0.0.1
     nameservers:
       addresses: [8.8.8.8,1.1.1.1]
```

Then, use the following command to apply the changes:

```
sudo netplan apply
```