# Need to set my ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: ip

I want to assign my ubuntu server 18.04 set with a static ip 192.168.0.225 could you please tell me what I should put in my 00-installer-config.yaml file.
Thank you

Does this help?

```
root@unbuntuserver2://etc# ifconfig
ens3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.210  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fef8:f9aa  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 52:54:00:f8:f9:aa  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 654103  bytes 234703817 (234.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 41  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 53799  bytes 21638774 (21.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 765  bytes 775782 (775.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 765  bytes 775782 (775.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:95:ab:d2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

.... and Yes, I can reserve 192.168.0.225 on my router.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I configure static IP on ubuntu server 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180607/how-can-i-configure-static-ip-on-ubuntu-server-18-04)

Comment: Thanks.  However I am very handicapped and can only use cut/paste so if you could give the exact content of the file I would be very thankful of you.

Comment: Then please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1325898/edit) your question and add in the name of the Ethernet NIC or the output of `ip addr` so that we can see what the name of the Ethernet is.  Also, we need to know if you are using the DNS from your router, or where the DNS is coming from like Google, etc.  Do you have your router set so that the IP address of `192.168.0.225` is reserved so no other device on the network will get that IP address?

Comment: What linux cmd can I use to get the info you need? Then I can just cut/paste the info for you. Thanks for your help!