# Network Manager not setting static ip

Tags: network-manager

I installed ubuntu server 20.04
I set a static ip during install
I have ethernet connection.
I installed Network Manager.
I enabled and started:
`#systemctl start NetworkManager`    `#systemctl enable NetworkManager`
I can only ssh.
But nothing happens as if only display but no function
I can"t change the static ip.
What a I doing wrong?

Comment: To configure a static IP address on a server installation, NetworkManager is not necessary. The network backend is controlled via networkd through a Netplan YAML configuration file. So I would personally remove NetworkManager and then configure your network interface via Netplan. Look in `/etc/netplan/` directory where there should be a YAML configuration file which you can edit. See here on how to configure: [How can I configure static IP on ubuntu server 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/1180613/1684306)

Comment: My goal is to set the static ip with a light weight gui ubuntu 20.04 is that possible...?

Answer (score 0):

I recommander you would set e.g `/etc/netplan/01-...yaml`file.You could read this document: [Netplan reads network configuration](https://netplan.io/)

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    wlsXXX:
      addresses:
      - 192.17.3.112/24
      dhcp4: no
      gateway4: 192.17.3.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 1.1.1.1
        - 8.8.8.4
```

Comment: I did that...it says it's being used but it is not changing my static ip...